# Python regex - extracting directories from path

Tags: python, regex, path, extract

I have a question about regex/Python. Sorry if this topic has been discussed millions of times - usually I find the answers on so/google etc. but I'm stuck in the millions of answers with this one.. (To be honest - I own a regex book, but somehow I'm too stupid to really understand it...)

For a music-management-system I need to extract information out of paths, providing different sets of options. Here two examples:

#### If the path is: (Case 1)

```
"/The Prodigy/The Fat Of The Land/04 - Funky Stuff.flac"
```

it should extract:

- artist: "The Prodigy"
- release: "The Fat Of The Land"
- Tracknumber: 4
- Title: "Funky Stuff"

#### And for eg: (Case 2)

```
"/[XLR 483] The Fat Of The Land/04 - The Prodigy - The  Funky Stuff.flac"
```

should extract:

- catno: "XLR 483"
- release: "The Fat Of The Land"
- Tracknumber: 4
- artist: "The Prodigy"
- Title: "Funky Stuff"

There is no need for a regex that covers both cases, these are just two examples. I'll then provide them as options (or starting-point to add own ones).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

@ S.Lott: I don't have a regex for this, I started with splitting the string:

```
parts = rel_path.split('/')       
track = parts[-1]
release = parts[-2]
artist = parts[-3]
```

but this looks like an extremely inflexible and un-elegant solution to me.

#### edit:

So far I have something like:

```
pattern = re.compile('^/(?P<artist>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/(?P<release>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/(?P<track>[a-zA-Z0-9 -_]+).[a-zA-Z]*.*')


rel_path = '/The Prodigy/The Fat Of The Land/04 - Funky Stuff.flac'

match = pattern.search(rel_path)

artist = match.group('artist')
release = match.group('release')
track = match.group('track')
```

Comment: Step 1.  Post the regexs you are using and the problems you're having.  We can help, but we dislike writing code for you.  Post the regex and what goes wrong with each one.

Comment: What's wrong with splitting the string?  It works, right?

Comment: @ S.Lott - it's nothing wrong with splitting, but it makes it difficult to have the pattern editable (outside the code). I'd like to provide (editable) presets in an admin-interface.

Comment: `a-zA-Z`?? Why aren't you using Unicode?

Comment: As stated above - maybe because I'm not smart enough to understand it... :)

Comment: "So far I have something like"?  And?  What's wrong with it?  Please be complete.

Comment: "have the pattern editable (outside the code"?  Why?  "I own a regex book, but somehow I'm too stupid to really understand it." seems to indicate that a regex isn't a good idea.  If you have trouble creating it, you'll probably have trouble maintaining it.  Why is a **regex** better than simple splits?  Please explain.

Comment: Why it is better (imo, maybe i'm wrong)..

Comment: Why it is better (imo, maybe i'm wrong)..
Consider the situation you have a lot of users importing music. They organize tracks tifferently. So they can choose from file/folder-layouts. But they can add own patterns as well.
eg default for iTunes: (artist/release/trackno title/)
    '^/(?P<artist>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/(?P<release>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/(?P<tracknumber>[ab]?\d+?)[ | - ](?P<track>[Ça-zA-Z0-9 -_]+)\.[a-zA-Z]+.*'
or another way: (release/trackno - artist - title)
    '^/(?P<release>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)/(?P<tracknumber>[ab]?\d+?)[ | -](?P<artist>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+) - (?P<track>[Ça-zA-Z0-9 -_]+)\.[a-zA-Z]+.*'

Comment: 0++ for The Fat of the Land.

Comment: RIP Keith Flint. March 2019.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although not necessary, but re is handy choice for this problem.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r"/(?P<artist>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?)/(?P<release>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?)/(?P<tracknumber>\d+?) - (?P<title>[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+?).flac")
s = "/The Prodigy/The Fat Of The Land/04 - Funky Stuff.flac"
m = pattern.search(s)
print m.group('artist')
print m.group('release')
print m.group('track number')
print m.group('title')
```

I use expressions such as `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` to explicitly specify the chars I expect in the string. It is just my preference to have a white-list-like regex to make the code more secure. There are many other ways to compose equivalent patterns. You will find all you need here http://docs.python.org/library/re.html, you don't need a book for that.

Comment: ? How does this exactly work? Don't understand this but looks like 
magic!

Answer (score 3):

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r'/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([0-9]*) - (.*)\.[^.]*')
artist,release,Tracknumber,Title = pattern1.match(file1).groups()

pattern2 = re.compile(r'/\[([^]]*)\] ([^/]*)/([0-9]*) - (.*) - (.*)\.[^.]*')
catno,release,Tracknumber,artist,Title = pattern2.match(file2).groups()
```

(where `file1` and `file2` are the paths you gave above).

First thing: you capture something matched by a regex with parentheses.  So everything between parentheses below will be spit back out as an item in the match.

Second: you match anything except a forward slash with regex code like `[^/]`.  So to match lots of things between forward slashes, you do `[^/]*`.

Putting those together, to capture the artist in your first sttring, you do `/([^/]*)/`.  Then you do that again to get the release.

Third: to match any digit, you use `[0-9]`.  So, to match any string of digits, you use `[0-9]*`.

Apply those principles repeatedly, and you should be able to understand the above.

Comment: Thanks, yes this helps. Did not know that you directly can assign groups() like this!

Comment: Yep.  `groups()` just returns a tuple, and this is a general way of assigning individual names to different parts of a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to the problem that you are having.

1. Do a split of path, and check if it's of len 4 (first case) or 3 ( second case).
2. Ignore the first element which should be a single '/' and for the second element, act on it to extract [xxx].
3. Split by '-' on the last element to get your other information.

If you have any specific doubts, in writing regex, edit your question and follow S.Lott's suggestion.

Comment: Ok. Thx - splitting works, but makes it difficult to edit in an admin-interface, as the logic sits completely in the code. Would have been my first approach as well :) , but was looking for a more modular solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should fist use `split` with the `/` delimiter so that you will be able to have informations just with the size of the array returned by `split`.

Then you can use regexp if you need. For instance, in the second case: (which happens only if you have two elements right?)

```
import re
item = "/[XLR 483] The Fat Of The Land/04 - The Prodigy - The  Funky Stuff.flac"
matches = re.search('^\/?\[([^\]]+)](.*)\/', item)
print matches.group(1) # 'XLR 483'
print matches.group(2) # ' The Fat Of The Land'
```

It may seems a bit complicated, but I have escaped all ambiguous characters so basically, the pattern is the following:

1. `^` at the beginning
2. `/?` there can be at most one slash `/` followed by...
3. `[` a curly brace
4. `([^\]]+)` containing all but a closing curly brace one or more times `+` (and please, capture the values, using the grouping parenthesis) and
5. `]` a closing curly brace followed by
6. `(.*)` anything but a linefeed (0 or more times `*`) captured via the parenthesis
7. and trailing slash `/`.

hope this helps!

Comment: Yes - I've been so far before.. But how to have it modular enough to assign it to variables - so that reversion of directories is possible..